# Proper way to build an Azure Web Site to have multiple services

Tags: wcf, azure, singleton, role

I need some guidance here on the Azure paradigm.  I am building a multi-user data model.  I want the core data model available as one set of services (e.g. a contract) on one URL, I want another set of services for managing the cache, statistics, start, stop, etc. on another URL (e.g. another contract for operator-type functions) and a third site for developer extensions (e.g. non-trivial, user-defined transactions).  All three of these services need to share the common data model.

I get the part where an Azure 'Role' is basically a VM.  After that, I'm stuck.  If I add three WCF Web Service Roles, I get three separate instances that can't communicate.  What is the recommended way to construct a solution/Azure Role to handle the case described above?

Comment: Unfortunately this is too broad and opinion-based for StackOverflow. You mentioned Azure roles (assuming you're talking about web/worker cloud services). But there are many many other services (VM's, web apps, API apps, mobile apps, cache services data services, analytics services, etc.). There is no "recommended" way to build an app. This would result in a debate/discussion.

Comment: I am not asking about VMs, Web Apps, etc.  There's no need to create a debate here where none exists.  I'm asking people who have experience with Azure for the correct paradigm for exploiting a 'Role' to handle two or more endpoints with a single, shared instance of data.

Comment: In that case: This type of question has been asked numerous times. Based on current StackOverflow guidelines, it's still off-topic as there's no "right" or "recommended" way. But... you might want to start with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9343920/272109) answer I posted about 4 years ago (prior to current guidelines), which should point you in the right starting direction when thinking about this.

Comment: David, all these solutions appear to be hacks.  The fact that you need this 'dummy' web role and have to manually hack the ServiceDefinition file is a big flag to me that we're not using the Azure model correctly.   Is it possible to solve this problem with multiple endpoints instead of full blown web sites?

Comment: Hack??? You really need to study roles then. It's a stateless VM. No hack. Been there since the beginning.

Comment: There is no rhyme or reason why only one web site is managed through the VS UI but the others need to be managed by hand.  It works, but it's ugly.  The deployment is almost as ugly as an MSI package.  It's a hack.

Comment: Obviously you've made up your mind. Think what you wish.  This isn't a discussion forum. Have a good day.