# Azure Web Role with Multiple Interfaces/Endpoints

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles

I've seen various attempts to place two or more web sites (URLs) on an Azure Cloud Service Web Role.  The solution is basically to hack up the ServiceDefinitions.csdef file which is a bit of overkill and doesn't appear to be supported by Visual Studio (VS forces you to have a dummy 'master' role and your web sites are manually patched into the configuration file.  This is a big red flag that the architecture of multiple websites in a single role isn't anticipated by Azure.)

Instead of hacking the config file, is it possible to create multiple endpoints and associate them with interfaces, such as with WCF?  As I mentioned in my original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265841/proper-way-to-build-an-azure-web-site-to-have-multiple-services), I have three ways I want the users to connect into an Azure 'Role': one for the data model (CRUD operations), one for the operator console (start, stop, statistics, etc.), one for the user-defined functions (the web site should be extensible).  I would like a separate endpoint for each of these major function groups (that is, well defined interfaces).  It's trivial to do in WCF but I don't see how it's done in Azure.

Comment: You really seem to be fixated on the term 'hack', as you propagate the term both in your other question and in this one - Web Roles and their associated csdef definition files have been around for about 6 years, with a very well documented schema. There is *no* hack - this is the config file you edit (just like you edit any other config file).

Answer (score 0):

Web Roles support up to 25 input endpoints per deployment, allowing you to host multiple services in the same role (independent of instance count), just by setting up your service to listen on a specific named endpoint which you create ahead of time (it's part of the service definition).

As you scale out to multiple instances, the input endpoints will likewise be load-balanced across your role instances.

Comment: The connection that I haven't been able to make yet is how these endpoints are associated with an interface.  In WCF, you make the association with the <EndPoint> element in the Web.Config.  Do I declare <EndPoint> tags in the ServiceDefinitions.csdef file to allocate the ports and then configure them normally in the Web.Config file?