# How do I enable LDAP support in PHP on a Windows Azure website?

Tags: php, iis, azure

I have been trying to enable LDAP support on a Windows Azure server without much luck.

I started by creating a **bin** directory at the root and uploading **php_ldap.dll** to it.

Next I added the following value under app settings:
Key: PHP_EXTENSIONS
Value: bin/php_ldap.dll

I restarted my server and the values show up in my phpinfo() but LDAP doesn't show up in my list of modules. One thing I noticed is that several of the articles I have read said I needed to add libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to my Windows path variable, but I can't see where I would do that in the Azure website configuration panel.

Comment: See if this question has an answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453614/windows-azure-support-for-other-technologies-than-net

Comment: That's not quite it. I suspect at this point that I need a way on Windows Azure to add libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to the Windows path variable, but can't find a way to do that.