# Is it possible to create ETW Events and listen to them on the same cloud service with multiple roles?

Tags: azure, cloud, etw

I have a worker role in which I generate ETW events through my `EventSource`. I want to have a separate worker role to persist those generated events using `TraceEvent` library and write them to Azure tables.

However, Azure cloud service creates instances of your roles and runs them on probably different VMs for which we don't have much control. I assume these two roles probably end up in different machines, so the second worker role would get nothing. Am I right?

The remaining option would be not to have that second worker role, but have that listener initialized as a `Startup Task` then. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a role is simply a virtual machine. Therefore, it is not possible to create a second role to listen events pushed to ETW from another role. The only option is to use [startup task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx) definition to kick off a background process (console application, windows service or some other application). [Here](http://mertemin.github.io/thoughts/2015/07/15/best-practices-of-deploying-windows-services-to-azure/) is a blog post describing how to create windows services and deploy along with cloud services.

More detailed answers on role definitions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236370/azure-roles-and-instances/9238438#9238438) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313143/run-multiple-workerroles-per-instance/5313889#5313889).